# An example of Vietoris–Rips complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

The below figure is from https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04019. I'm new to the concept of the simplicial complex and studying it through the article. The given definition of Vietoris–Rips complex $\text{Rips}_{\delta}(X)$ of the points in $X$ is "the set of simplicies $[x_0, \cdots, x_k]$ such that $d(x_i, x_j) \le \delta$ for all $(i, j)$" where $d$ is a metric. I cannot understand why the Vietoris–Rips complex with radius $2 \alpha$ in this figure (the right one) has the tetrahedron. The distance between the upper point and the bottom point of the tetrahedron is larger than $2 \alpha$, and so they cannot be in a simplex. I think the bottom part should be the same with the left one. Do I misunderstand something?

[image]

Comment: It is just an inaccurate picture, whose main goal was to illustrate the difference between Chech and Rips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right and the authors of the paper are just sloppy with their pictures.

Comment: @madprob: What I wrote, does provide a full answer.

Comment: Sorry! You are right.